# What are the ways to publish apps/sheets from Qliksense?

Tags: business-intelligence, qlikview, qliksense, qlik-expression

I have Sales database which contains sales data along with manager IDs, I have created the required reports in Qliksense and want to use Qliksense reports on custom UI (on an app).Also want to apply row level security so that one manager would be able to see only his data and other data would be restricted for him.
How to publish these reports on custom UI and provide data security using Qliksense Desktop or cloud?
PS - I do not have enterprise version yet.

Comment: What do you mean by "custom UI"?

Comment: By custom UI I meant the report will be embedded in the script to display on the Web browser or in an app.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to go the dev hub and copy the iframe / embed script from there. It is under the single configurator menu item

[image: Dev Hub]

[image: Dev hub options]

The standard desktop version will not allow for row level security in any way you must have a license to do that. But once licensed that security will flow naturally to the iframe / embedded object